# Differential equations systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, systems-of-equations

We have that system of differential equations: $$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
x'=-x \\ 
y'=-2y \\  
\end{array} 
\right.
$$
I have to solve that system but I only know the method of derive first equation and substitute in the second and get a second order differential equation which I know to solve. But it seems that that method doesn't work here. How can I solve it? I'm beginner at this kind of exercises.
Thanks!

Comment: Actually the method you are using is more complicated than what you need here! Can you think of any function whose derivative would be minus itself? ($f' = -f$)

Answer (score 1):

These are two unrelated DE's and you have to solve them independently. The answer is $x(t)=ce^{-t}$ and $y=de^{-2t}$ where $c$ and $d$ are constants.

Answer (score 1):

This system is just a collection of 2 uncoupled ODEs, and so can be solved separately, just as we would a simple 1st order ODE.